# How do I generate a list of the characters occurring before a certain character only in lines that contain another certain character using regex?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
407-OL?
408-2-OL?
408-OL?
418-het?
420-1 and 2- OL?
429-2-left unscored?
430-2-left both unscored?
431-1 and 2- Ri??
436-1-just homozygote?
444-2-het? ins. both
456-2-ins 246 despite slight OL
456-1-ins 245 (weaker)
457-2-Ri?
```

I want it to return the numbers on the left (before the dash), but only for lines that contain a question mark. In other words, I want this to be the output:

```
407
408
408
418
420
429
430
431
436
444
457
```

Comment: To clarify further, there is a new line before each number with a dash:
407-OL? '\n'
408-OL? '\n'
etc. etc.

Comment: After reading the question title, I just realized how awkward translating `sed` to English would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably easiest method: `cat some_file | grep '?' | cut -d'-' -f1`

- `cat somefile` => feed the contents of `some_file` into the pipe
- `grep '?'` => filter only lines containing a `?`
- `cut -d'-' -f1` => divide the string into fields with `-` as field separator, then print field #1

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much! It worked!

Comment: Make a `touch a` then try again. Will not work anymore. `?` is a wildcard character and should be escaped or quoted.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I can't reproduce it. `grep ?` should be replaced by `grep '\?'`, is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean “escape _or_ quote”. So either `grep \?` or `grep '?'` or `grep "?"`. Otherwise the shell will perform wildcard expansion and `?` will be replaced with the list of matching files – all files in the current directory with single character long names.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Oh wow. Didn't even notice that the output was all-inclusive. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Typically a task for `sed` or `awk`:

```
sed -n '/?/s/-.*//p' some_file

awk -F- '/\?/{print$1}' some_file
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier would be to catch each number by `^\d+` regex, for example:

```
grep '?' file.txt | grep -o '^\d\+'
```

where:

- `^` beginning of the line
- `\d\+` matches any digit character more than once